# gulp Cannot find module 'readable-stream/transform'

Tags: node.js, git, gulp, laravel-5.1

when I run gulp in my windows 7 I got this

```
<pre>
c:\wamp\www\laravel>gulp
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream/transform'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\wamp\www\laravel\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\through2\through2.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
</pre>
```

and when I run

```
c:\wamp\www\laravel>npm install readable-stream/transform --save
```

I got this

```
 <pre>

c:\wamp\www\laravel>npm install readable-stream/transform --save
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:203:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  readable-stream/transform resetting remote C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-118dcd777892d6f074056363a382a654 because of error: { [Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit ]
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-118dcd777892d6f074056363a382a654: Cloning into bar
e repository 'C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-118dcd777892d6f074056363a382a654'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-118dcd777892d6f074056363a382a654: fatal: remote er
ror:
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-118dcd777892d6f074056363a382a654:   Repository not
 found.
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:203:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  readable-stream/transform resetting remote C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-5b2633ac60de63f56f8df5b95ac9a72d because of error: { [Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origi
n.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit ]
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-5b2633ac60de63f56f8df5b95ac9a72d: Cloning
into bare repository 'C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-5b2633ac60de63f56f8df5b95ac9a72d'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-5b2633ac60de63f56f8df5b95ac9a72d: remote:
Invalid username or password.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-5b2633ac60de63f56f8df5b95ac9a72d: fatal: A
uthentication failed for 'https://github.com/readable-stream/transform.git/'
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:203:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  readable-stream/transform resetting remote C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-47d9697875e1d858d205c96d8adf2ff0 because of error: { [Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit ]
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-47d9697875e1d858d205c96d8adf2ff0: Cloning into bare
repository 'C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-47d9697875e1d858d205c96d8adf2ff0'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-47d9697875e1d858d205c96d8adf2ff0: Permission denied
(publickey).
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-47d9697875e1d858d205c96d8adf2ff0: fatal: Could not r
ead from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-47d9697875e1d858d205c96d8adf2ff0:
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-47d9697875e1d858d205c96d8adf2ff0: Please make sure y
ou have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-47d9697875e1d858d205c96d8adf2ff0: and the repository
 exists.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\a0455\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "readable-stream/transform" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.4.0
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:readable-stream/transform.git C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-47d9697875e1d
858d205c96d8adf2ff0
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-47d9697875e1d858d205c96d8adf2ff0'...
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\wamp\www\laravel\npm-debug.log
</pre>
```

seems like there is

```
 Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\a0455\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-readable-stream-transform-git-47d9697875e1d858d205c96d8adf2ff0'...
 Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.


 If you need help, you may report this error at:
```

Now I don't know what to do.  I need to run gulp to generate style sheet in laravel.  if anyone has come across this kind of problem before.  Please help.
and by the way my node js version is 3.4.0

```
c:\wamp\www\laravel>npm -v
3.4.0
```

thank you so much

Sura

Answer (score 0):

use `npmd` or just do

```
$ rm -rf node_modules

$ npm i
```