# Gulp failed after push

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, azure, gulp

So I did this tutorial,(The basic Azure Cosmos DB (MongoDB) with Node.js)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-nodejs-mongodb-app

I didn't changed anything in the code just what tutorial says and after
`git push azure master` I get 
[gulp failed(link to image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9nSE.png)

Does anyone have any clues from what comes this error?

Edit: `deploy.sh` Gulp part

```
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/gulpfile.js" ]; then
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
    eval ./node_modules/.bin/gulp imagemin
   eval ./node_modules/.bin/gulp prod    <----I added this line and still fails
  exitWithMessageOnError "gulp failed"
  cd - > /dev/null
fi
```

`package.json` only Gulp part

```
{
  "name": "meanjs",
  "description": "Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js.",
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "meanjs-version": "0.5.0",
  "private": false,
  "author": "https://github.com/meanjs/mean/graphs/contributors",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/meanjs/mean.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.1",
    "npm": "3.10.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "update": "npm update && npm prune && npm run bower",
    "clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ public/lib/",
    "reinstall": "npm cache clean && npm run clean && npm install",
    "start": "gulp",
    "start:prod": "gulp prod",
    "start:debug": "node-debug --web-host 0.0.0.0 server.js & gulp debug",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "bower": "bower install --allow-root && bower prune --allow-root",
    "lint": "gulp lint",
    "test": "gulp test",
    "test:server": "gulp test:server",
    "test:server:watch": "gulp test:server:watch",
    "test:client": "gulp test:client",
    "test:e2e": "gulp test:e2e",
    "test:coverage": "gulp test:coverage",
    "postinstall": "npm run bower",
    "generate-ssl-certs": "scripts/generate-ssl-certs.sh"
  },
  "dependencies": {

    "passport-google-oauth": "~1.0.0",
    "passport-linkedin": "~1.0.0",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "passport-paypal-openidconnect": "~0.1.1",
    "passport-twitter": "~1.0.4",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.2",
    "validator": "~7.0.0",
    "winston": "^2.3.1",
    "wiredep": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "~2.6.0",
    "gulp-csslint": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-csso": "~3.0.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "~3.0.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "~3.2.0",
    "gulp-istanbul": "~1.1.1",
    "gulp-less": "~3.3.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~1.5.0",
    "gulp-mocha": "~3.0.1",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "~2.2.1",
    "gulp-protractor": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-refresh": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-rev": "^7.1.2",
    "gulp-sass": "~3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~2.1.2",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.7",
  }
}
```

I also get this error on the begin of the push logs

```
remote: glob error { Error: ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, scandir 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\phant
omjs-prebuilt\node_modules\request\node_modules\http-signature\node_modules\sshpk\bin\sshpk-conv'
remote:     at Error (native)
```

Edit2: The error changed a bit

```
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote:     throw err;
remote: gulp failed
remote:           ^
remote: Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream/transform'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may have noticed when posting your question that you would have been told you lack the reputation to post images within it. The reason for this cap is "We really do not want you to post images", and we hope you learn that lesson by the time your reputation increases to allow posting them. The reason we do not want them is because "your error output is from a terminal and in **text**". Just like the code you write is in "text" and just like the question is worded in "text. Please post errors and code as "text" **only**. No screenshots please.

Comment: That said. The specific errors in your screenshot seem to indicate that you actually missed the `npm install` step completely. I would suggest following your tutorial from the beginning again, and probably best with a clean directory to start in. Follow **all** the instructions this time.

Comment: npm install was executed, I get this error from the server part where Azure executes npm install ,not me

Comment: Also you clearly did not [install gulp](https://nodejs.org/). There is a list of prerequisites on that page. Stop and start again and actually follow all the instructions.

Comment: If the server runs locally means that I didn't installed gulp ? I installed it and get updated 1 package in 51.731s so it was there

Answer (score 0):

You did install `gulp`.  Make sure you [have installed gulp-cli](http://gulpjs.com/).
And, as mentioned in "[no command '`gulp`' found - after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22274098/6309)"

> Also, `node_modules/.bin/` isn't in your `%PATH%`.
>   But it is automatically added by `npm` when running `npm` scripts (see [this blog post for reference](http://substack.net/task_automation_with_npm_run)).

Comment: I installed it, the part with PATH I don't understand,I don't know how Azure server has the path set

Comment: @KingTsunamy you can modify deploy.sh in order for the script to display its PATH: that will give a clue

Comment: It seems that .bin part is added ,I edited my post with gulp part from deploy.sh

Comment: @KingTsunamy What the package.json includes? Also https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1128#issuecomment-117856541

Comment: @KingTsunamy gulp 3, I see: https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/package.json#L82

Comment: @KingTsunamy Any luck deleting `~/.nmp` and `node_modules` to see if `gulp` in  then shows up in `./node_modules/.bin/`?

Comment: Yes I  tried,same error but twice because I added another line in deploy.sh

Comment: I updated the post,I just saw an error at begin,maybe that affect the result of the gulp installation

Comment: Strange indeed. https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/142#issuecomment-206185448

Comment: @KingTsunamy Also, same case here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2299#issuecomment-307927280

Comment: @KingTsunamy Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/35153955/6309 help? (even though this is Azure, not a local Windows installation)

Comment: No,those made me think maybe the NOD_ENV variable is not set,I set it in the source file but the error doesn't dissapear

Comment: Now I see at begin Invalid start-up command "gulp" in package.json. Please use the format "node <script relative path>".

Comment: @KingTsunamy you mean as setting NODE_ENV  to production? (https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/e596375b62e65dfac7cf4154aa20c7cfd3207c75/modules/core/tests/server/core.server.config.tests.js#L99)

Comment: Yes,it must be production

Comment: I added the new error,I uploaded with kudu console the node_modules folder and got that error

Comment: @KingTsunamy And again, deleting node_modules would not help? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33749751/6309) (https://github.com/rvagg/through2/issues/39#issuecomment-114261710)

Comment: tried now I get bower error,seems that is from Azure server the error,I tried second time the server stopped because I used too much of the CPU